# Pyspark; Using ReduceByKey on list values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to get a better understanding of the reduceByKey function and have been exploring ways of using it to complete different tasks. I would like to apply the the RDD data shown below. The format for a row of data is a tuple with a name and then a list of all the dates associated to that name (Below is a copy of how the data looks)

```
data = [("Cassavetes, Frank", ['2012', '2002', '2009', '2005']),
("Knight, Shirley (I)", ['1997', '2002', '2009']),
("Yip, Françoise", ['2007', '2004', '2000']),
("Danner, Blythe", ['2000', '2008', '2012', '2010', '2004', '2004', '1999', '1998']),
("Buck (X)", ['2002', '2006', '2009'])]
```

In an attempt to get a count of all the dates associated to each name in the tuples, I applied the code below, using the reduceByKey function to try and convert the list of dates into a sum of the number of dates in the list.

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
reducedRdd = rdd.reduceByKey( lambda a,b: len(a.split(" ")) + len(b.split(" ")) )
reducedRdd.take(1)
```

The code above produces the same results as the input data and does not carry out any of the transformations listed in the reduce function, below is an example of the code's output:

```
[('Yip, Françoise', ['2007', '2004', '2000'])]
```

The output I expected is as follows;

```
[("Yip, Françoise", 3)]
```

Why is it that the code I wrote above does not give me my expected output and how would I alter it to ensure it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a `map`, not a `reduceByKey`. There is nothing to reduce, because your data is already grouped by key, so nothing is done on your RDD and you got back the original RDD.

```
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], len(x[1])))

print(rdd2.collect())
# [('Cassavetes, Frank', 4), ('Knight, Shirley (I)', 3), ('Yip, Françoise', 3), ('Danner, Blythe', 8), ('Buck (X)', 3)]
```

`mapValues` might be even more appropriate:

```
rdd2 = rdd.mapValues(len)

print(rdd2.collect())
# [('Cassavetes, Frank', 4), ('Knight, Shirley (I)', 3), ('Yip, Françoise', 3), ('Danner, Blythe', 8), ('Buck (X)', 3)]
```

---

If you want to use `reduceByKey`, your data should be ungrouped. e.g. if you have

```
data = [('Cassavetes, Frank', '2012'), ('Cassavetes, Frank', '2002'), ('Cassavetes, Frank', '2009'), ('Cassavetes, Frank', '2005'), ('Knight, Shirley (I)', '1997'), ('Knight, Shirley (I)', '2002'), ('Knight, Shirley (I)', '2009'), ('Yip, Françoise', '2007'), ('Yip, Françoise', '2004'), ('Yip, Françoise', '2000'), ('Danner, Blythe', '2000'), ('Danner, Blythe', '2008'), ('Danner, Blythe', '2012'), ('Danner, Blythe', '2010'), ('Danner, Blythe', '2004'), ('Danner, Blythe', '2004'), ('Danner, Blythe', '1999'), ('Danner, Blythe', '1998'), ('Buck (X)', '2002'), ('Buck (X)', '2006'), ('Buck (X)', '2009')]
```

then you can do

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

from operator import add
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], 1)).reduceByKey(add)

rdd2.collect()
# [('Yip, Françoise', 3), ('Cassavetes, Frank', 4), ('Knight, Shirley (I)', 3), ('Danner, Blythe', 8), ('Buck (X)', 3)]
```

Comment: That makes sense, i wanted to avoid using the map functions since the exercise was about exploring the reduce functions (reduce or reduceByKey). Is this kind of thing (performing reduce output calculations on grouped values such as the lists in my dataset) not possible without using a map function ?

Comment: The thing is, your data is **already** grouped, so `reduce` will do nothing, but if your original data is ungrouped, you can use `reduce`.

Comment: I have added an example which uses `reduceByKey`. See if it's helpful to you :)

Comment: Looking back at this, I have tried to use reduceByKey on the ungrounded Data with the following code ; rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: len(a)+len(b)) but when i try to do this and have a look at the output using the take function, i get an error ; "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()". I could only get it to work by forcing the variables `a` and `b` in my lambda expression into strings using the following code; `rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: len(str(a))+len(str(b)))`. Why is it that my variables a and b are being read as ints rather than strings (which is what the years are).

Comment: Why are you trying to get the length of the years?

Comment: Yes, but it could even be switched around where the key is the years and the length is the name. My worry concern is less about exactly what the outcome is and more about why i am getting the type error as from what i can see there is no way that those variables a and b are ints.

Comment: I'll need to see more code to reach a conclusion. It would be good if you can open another question and provide the necessary details. There is not enough space in the comments section here.